# Memory leaks using unique pointers

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, unique-ptr

I created an array of unique pointers

```
std::unique_ptr<TextItem> mTextItems[6];
```

And then I created a method to created some TextItems

```
void InitializeTexts() 
{
    for (auto& item : mTextItems) {
        item.reset(new TextItem("", mFont->GetTTF(), mWindow->GetRenderer()));
    }
}
```

In the output window of visual studio I always get a memory leak message 6 times which points towards the item.reset line.

```
: {208} normal block at 0x0A35AC48, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < $?     PT   i  > C4 24 3F 00 00 00 00 00 50 54 C9 00 90 69 C9 00
```

I have a similar method for sprites and there it happens as well.

This is the first time I am using smart pointers so I don't really know how to clean this up properly.

Comment: It's doubtful the lines shown are responsible for the leak. How did you narrow down the leak to those lines?

Comment: I used this link to write the lines of the memory leak as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2017

Comment: Does it still happen if you use: `item = std::make_unique<TextItem>("", mFont->GetTTF(), mWindow->GetRenderer()));`

Comment: Are you certain the object containing `mTextItems` is itself being destroyed correctly?

Comment: @Frank - Good suggestion. Certainly, if running that code with int instead of TextItem, there is no leak.

Comment: @keith Thanks, this solved it! I don't 100% understand why though.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. On a positive note, you should avoid using `new` with `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`, so using `std::make_unique` is preferable anyway :-)

Comment: Btw there is Visual Leak Detector with more features than the CRT one: https://kinddragon.github.io/vld/

Comment: It's a good idea to check with some profiler like Deleaker. It might happen that `mTextItems` is destroyed in a destructor of a global object, and Visual Studio shows leaks before the destructor is called. But it's strange that it shows nothing when `int` is used.